# I am new to PHP+MySql,and trying to write a simple script that will delete a user from the database,,but i am not getting rid of a error

Tags: php, mysql

This is my whole code to delete a user:

```
 <?php
  $page_title = 'Delete a User';
  include ('includes/header.html');
   echo '<h1>Delete a User</h1>';

   if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ) { // From view_users.php
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     } elseif ( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ) { // sbmsn
 $id = $_POST['id'];
     } else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
include ('includes/footer.html'); 
exit();

    }

  require_once ('../connect.php');

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if($_POST['sure'] == 'Yes') {
    $q="DELETE FROM user WHERE user_id= $id ";
    $r= @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {
        echo '<p>The user has been deleted</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<p class="error">Sorry! the user could not be deleted.</p>';
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br/>Query: '.$q. '</p>';
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>The user has not been deleted.</p>';
}
   }
    else {
$q="SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE user_id=$id";
$r= @mysqli_query($dbc,$q);

if(mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM);

    echo "<h3>Name: $row[0]</h3> Are you sure you want to delete this user?";
    echo '<form action="delete_user.php" method="post">
      <p> <input type="radio" name="sure" value="Yes" />Yes</p>
      <p> <input type="radio" name="sure" value="No" checked="checked" />No</p>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value=" '.$id.' "/>

    </form>';
}
else {
    echo '<p class="error">ERROR Sorry!</p>';
}
  }

   mysqli_close($dbc);

  include ('includes/footer.html');
 ?>
```

but every time I am getting error of

```
This page has been accessed in error
```

The `$id` stuff is working on a same kind of script to edit the informations of users.

Comment: how are you getting to this page? give example of URL if `GET`

Comment: You're correctly using mysqli instead of mysql -- why aren't you using prepared statements?

Comment: Instead of checking both `$_GET` and `$_POST`, why not use `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: remove every @, suppressing errors will never help you fix your code.

Comment: Finally a person using `mysqli` not `mysql`.

Comment: Can you post the form used to submit to this script?

Comment: @UnholyRanger   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<tr>
           <td align="left"><a href="edit_user.php?id=' .$row['user_id'].' ">Edit</a></td>
           <td align="left"><a href="delete_user.php?id=' .$row['user_id'].' ">Delete</a></td>   </tr>';
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

//Access From view_users.php?id=1;
//Access via form input with name "id" submitted via get or post methods
//You might want to do an integer casting (int)$_REQUEST['id']; //Not very necessary

  $page_title = 'Delete a User';
  include ('includes/header.html');
   echo '<h1>Delete a User</h1>';

   if ( (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) && (is_numeric(trim($_REQUEST['id']))) ) { // From view_users.php
     $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_REQUEST['id'])); //Be paranoid about security
     } else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
include ('includes/footer.html'); 
exit();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has nothing to do with the SQL. The problem is located within this code:

```
if ( (isset($_GET['id'])) && (is_numeric($_GET['id'])) ) { // From view_users.php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} elseif ( (isset($_POST['id'])) && (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) ) { // sbmsn
    $id = $_POST['id'];
} else { // No valid ID, kill the script.
    echo '<p class="error">This page has been accessed in error.</p>';
    include ('includes/footer.html'); 
    exit();
}
```

So, this would mean that the following are true:

1. `$_GET['id']` is not numeric or is not set
2. `$_POST['id']` is not numeric or is not set

Check what is being sent to this page.

To debug, first insert `print_r($_GET); print_r($_POST);` at top of the page and look at the output. If `$_GET` and `$_POST` are empty, then nothing is being sent to this page. If they have a value, they are probably not numeric. Fix as needed from here on.

Comment: on GET:Array ( [id] => 6 ) Array ( ) ,,,,,,,
on POST:Array ( ) Array ( [sure] => Yes [submit] => submit [id] => 6 )

Comment: Hmmm... Okay, this may sound stupid, but try running `echo isset($_GET['id'])`, `echo is_numeric($_GET['id'])`, `echo isset($_POST['id'])` and `echo is_numeric($_POST['id'])`, post the result of each value.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is is_numeric($_GET['id']) or is_numeric($_POST['id']). You post a string and it detects the string as an string not a number.

Comment: not exactly true. `is_numeric` will detect `$var = "2";` as true

Comment: Could you send me the result of print_r($_POST)?